# Org-mode only export LaTex Source Blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

I'm looking to use org-mode to typeset homework for a math class I'm taking and was wondering if there is a way to export only certain LaTex blocks to the final PDF using org-babel.  As an example consider

```
** TODO [#A] Question 1
   DEADLINE: <2017-01-17 Tue>
   Notes about the problem and links to resources would go here.
   #+BEGIN_SRC latex
     \begin{exercise}{1}
       Prove the theorem
     \end{exercise}
     \begin{proof}
       Let $x \in A$ blah blah.....
     \end{proof}
   #+END_SRC
```

When exporting to PDF I would only want the LaTex code to show up in the PDF but not the TODO heading or any of the other notes and links that might be below it.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/orgmode/comments/5omspv/is_it_possible_to_only_export_latex_source_blocks/), I found that this can be accomplished using [org-babel-tangle](http://orgmode.org/manual/Extracting-source-code.html).

Comment: But then you have to compile the resulting tex code by hand, haven't you?  I'd rather try export filters: http://orgmode.org/org.html#Advanced-configuration.